# How to setup devops pipeline to save nginx files/parameters in git?

Tags: nginx, jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, devops

1. There is a Devops pipeline where it saves configuration files/parameters in repo like Git.
2. Automation tools like Jenkins/Ansible need to continuously check the changes in repo and
   pickup the change in config file.
3. Based on the configuration, automation tool needs to check if ngnix plus is already running in AWS cloud or not.
4. If  it is already running ngnix plus instance then apply the new
   changes in ngnix plus config based on repo changes.

How can I achieve this objective??

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This question is overly broad as well as subject to bring a lot of opinion based answers and might even be related to an other stackexchange site. Please take some time to visit the help section. You can start with [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can also check https://devops.stackexchange.com/ that might be better suited for this.

Comment: The best solution would be to hire a guy who can do this. It's pretty simple when you know all tech involved.